# DropWizard not registering my health check

Tags: java, dropwizard, health-monitoring, codahale-metrics

In my DropWizard (**v0.7.0**) app, I have a `DummyHealthCheck` like so:

```
public class DummyHealthCheck extends HealthCheck {
    @Override
    protected Result check() throws Exception {
        return Result.healthy();
    }
}
```

Then in my main `Application` impl:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfiguration> {
    @Override
    public void run(MyConfiguration configuration, Environment environment)
            throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(new DummyHealthCheck());
    }
}
```

When I start up the server, it starts successfuly (no exceptions/errors), however I get the following message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!    THIS APPLICATION HAS NO HEALTHCHECKS. THIS MEANS YOU WILL NEVER KNOW      !
!     IF IT DIES IN PRODUCTION, WHICH MEANS YOU WILL NEVER KNOW IF YOU'RE      !
!    LETTING YOUR USERS DOWN. YOU SHOULD ADD A HEALTHCHECK FOR EACH OF YOUR    !
!         APPLICATION'S DEPENDENCIES WHICH FULLY (BUT LIGHTLY) TESTS IT.       !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:8081/healthcheck` I see:

```
{"deadlocks":{"healthy":true}}
```

1. What is going on here? How do I register my health check?
2. Also, I have configured DropWizard to use SSL (self-signed) on port 8443; I have verified this works with my normal endpoints. I am surprised, however, to see that my **admin app** is still exposed on 8081 over HTTP. How do I configure it for HTTPS as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Question 1:

You don't register it with Jersey, as Health Checks are DropWizard specific. They should be registered as follows

```
environment.healthChecks().register("dummy", new DummyHealthCheck());
```

as explained [here](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.12/docs/manual/core.html#health-checks). If it *was* registered as above, you would see

```
{"deadlocks":{"healthy":true}, "dummy":{"healthy":true}}
```

### Question 2:

I assume you already have done something similar to

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: https
      port: 8443
      keyStorePath: example.keystore
      keyStorePassword: example
      validateCerts: false
```

in your yaml, as seen [here](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#ssl). That is just for the application. You will also need to configure the admin

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - ...
  adminConnectors:
  - type: https
    port: 8444    // should a different port from the application
    keyStorePath: example.keystore
    keyStorePassword: example
    validateCerts: false
```

Comment: @IAmYourFaja you really need an IDE! It helps you so much :)